# wikipedia regex match and replace

Tags: java, regex, wikipedia

I am working on a media wiki xml that wikipedia provides and I'm trying to the preprocess the data removing and replacing some of specific expressions in the text. One such preprocessing is to replace all the internal links to wikipedia pages as follows -

Input -

> text here [[foo|bar]] text here [[some.jpg|some|this is an image of some]] text here

Output -

> text here foo bar text here some.jpg some this is an image of some text here

This is what I have been able to achieve for now -

```
String regex = "(\\[\\[(.+?)\\]\\]*)"; 
string.replaceAll(regex, "$2"));
```

This helps me remove the `[[]]` from the text. But I'm kind of stuck trying to replace the pipes `"|"` with a space `" "`.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `\\[\\[|\\||]]` wouldn't suit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to clean a set of special chars, simply match these chars

```
string.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\|\\s]+", " ");
```

Comment: First, I thought I'd need to process the special form separately. But this works too actually. I think I over-thought a simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the duplicate space problem:

```
String regex = " \\[{2}|\\]{2} |\\|";
String result = subject.replaceAll(regex, " ");
```

If you want to check that the square brackets and pipes you remove are really parts of the structure you are looking for *(i.e. `[[word1|word2|...|wordN]]`)*, you can also use a `\G` based pattern:

```
String regex = "(?:\\G(?!\\A)\\|| ?\\[\\[(?=[^\\]\\[|]+(?:\\|[^\\]\\[|]+)*+\\]\\]))([^\\]\\[|]+)(?>\\]\\])?";
String result = subject.replaceAll(regex, " $1");
```

[demo](http://fiddle.re/6k7fcn)

Pattern details:

```
(?: # two possible starts:
    \G (?!\A) \| # 1) a start contiguous to the previous match
  | # OR
    [ ]? \[\[ # 2) the double opening square brackets
    (?= # a lookahead to test if the format is the good one
        [^\]\[|]+ (?:\| [^\]\[|]+)*+ \]\]
    )
)
([^\]\[|]+) # capture the item in group 1
(?>\]\])? # eventual double closing square brackets
```